# Restricted regression: dropping some factor levels in R

Tags: r, regression, r-factor

I want to evaluate a joint hypothesis which claims three levels of a factor are zero, and haven't found a way to do so that isn't overly manual.

My MRE:

```
# data setup
## manually assign dummies for the method I can make work
airquality[paste0("Month", 5:9)] = 
  lapply(5:9, function(mo) airquality$Month == mo)

## ideal approach would use factors
airquality$Month = as.factor(airquality$Month)
```

In `airquality`, `Month` can be any of `5:9`. I want to (arbitrarily in this example) evaluate the hypothesis that the coefficients on months `6:8` are jointly zero in `Solar.R ~ Temp + Month` (I'll use a Wald test here).

The simplest specification of the unrestricted model is:

```
(reg1 <- lm(Solar.R ~ Temp + Month, data = airquality))
# Call:
# lm(formula = Solar.R ~ Temp + Month, data = airquality)
# 
# Coefficients:
# (Intercept)         Temp       Month6       Month7       Month8  
#    -107.655        4.385      -49.066      -43.813      -87.768  
#      Month9  
#     -62.151
```

To use `lmtest::waldtest`, I should supply a restricted model; in this case, that restricted model would include `Month9` but force the coefficients on only `Month6`, `Month7` and `Month8` to be 0 (i.e., exclude those levels, but *include* `Month9`).

This is *not* what `factor(., exclude = 6:9)` accomplishes:

```
(reg2 <- lm(Solar.R ~ Temp + 
              factor(Month, exclude = c(6, 7, 8)), 
            data = airquality))
# Call:
# lm(formula = Solar.R ~ Temp + factor(Month, exclude = c(6, 7, 
#     8)), data = airquality)
# 
# Coefficients:
#                          (Intercept)  
#                              -55.592  
#                                 Temp  
#                                3.595  
# factor(Month, exclude = c(6, 7, 8))9  
#                              -53.451
```

The correct outcome of the restricted model is:

```
(reg3 <- lm(Solar.R ~ Temp + Month9, data = airquality))
# Call:
# lm(formula = Solar.R ~ Temp + Month9, data = airquality)
# 
# Coefficients:
# (Intercept)         Temp   Month9TRUE  
#     -16.030        2.636      -19.246
```

However, `lmtest::waldtest` doesn't understand that the models are nested:

```
library(lmtest)
waldtest(reg1, reg3)
```

> Error in `modelCompare(objects[[i - 1]], objects[[i]], vfun = vcov0)` : 
>     models are not nested

So I have to replace `reg1`:

```
reg4 <- lm(Solar.R ~ ., data = 
             airquality[ , c("Solar.R", "Temp", 
                             paste0("Month", 6:9))])
waldtest(reg4, reg3)
# Wald test
#
# Model 1: Solar.R ~ Temp + Month6 + Month7 + Month8 + Month9
# Model 2: Solar.R ~ Temp + Month9
#   Res.Df Df     F  Pr(>F)  
# 1    140                   
# 2    143 -3 3.182 0.02594 *
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’
```

Is there no more parsimonious/intuitive way of going about running this test?

The documentation for `?waldtest` suggests I should be able to specify in the second argument terms to exclude, but this doesn't apply to `factor`s:

```
waldtest(reg1, paste0("Month", 6:8))
```

> Error in `modelUpdate(objects[[i - 1]], objects[[i]])` : 
>     empty model specification
>
> In addition: Warning message:
>
> In `modelUpdate(objects[[i - 1]], objects[[i]])` :
>     terms specified that are not in the model: `“Month6”`, `“Month7”`, `“Month8”`

Comment: Maybe my memory is faulty ,but I thought the `glht` function in `pkg:multcomp` was a direct answer to this.

Comment: If your factor does not have an unwieldy number of levels you can convert the factor to dummies using the `model.matrix()` command and then choose which contrasts to include manually.

Comment: @GabrielFGeislerMesevage how is this different from what I proposed in the question? I'm not following